# Fourier Transform of a Periodic function

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have some questions regarding Fourier series and the Fourier transform.

The frequencyspectum consists of the Cn's of the Fourier series of a periodic function. The Fourier transform does the same thing for non-periodic functions.

Now does the Fourier transform of a PERIODIC function give the same spectrum as those Cn terms ?

Extra question: we should be able to draw the spectrum in our classes. With the frequency on the x-axis and |Cn| on the y-axis. If Cn is complex or negative does that mean I still draw a line upwards because of |Cn| ?

Thank you all

Comment: The $c_n$ terms are complex numbers and the absolute value of a complex number is a non-negative real number.

Comment: Thank you, I just wasn't sure :d

Comment: It's okay. Furthermore the fourier spectrum of a periodic function is guaranteed to have "spikes" at integer multiples of the base frequency. I should probably draw an image.

Comment: So the Fourier transform of a periodic function also gives me these determined spikes, delta functions I suppose?

Comment: Yes, the continous fourier transform gives us that, and the discrete gives us the discrete counterparts to the delta functions, but only if we hit exactly on the base frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Fourier spectrum of a periodic function $f(x) = \cos(kx+1)^{24}$, in theory we have infinitesmally tight spikes at even intervals and 0 everywhere else. If you have learned distributions those are called **Dirac distributions** but numerically often one will have to be satisfied with a very pointy peak in the spectrum of the discrete fourier transform because the spectrum must align perfectly to fit theory.

[image]

As you can see there is the same distance in frequencies between each peak. That is what happens when doing the Fourier Transform to a function which has a fourier series.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I learned that distribution!

Comment: If f(x)=cos(200t)cos(700t), The Fourier transform does not seem to have that property (the same distance between peaks), I believe they are at w=500 and w=900. What is going on here ? f(x) surely is periodic

Comment: A product becomes a convolution in the fourier domain, so you may need to consider another base frequency. Maybe a least common divisor or so.

Comment: @mathreadler Would you please describe more precisely what exactly is on the image? In what sense does the fourier transform of a periodic function give such spikes? What function do you integrate across $\mathbb{R}$ so that it gives what is on the image? I would expect $f$ restricted $\langle -N,N \rangle$ should give something more like a sum of sinc functions.

Comment: @JohnP sure I will try to do so in weekend, but now work.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you. I think I realize now that the picture might show up if we take the fourier transform of $f$ multiplied with $e^{-x^2 / n}$ and go with $n$ to infinity, but in some sense I'm not sure why it's alright to pick this way of "approximating" $f$, as opposed to say $f \cdot rect_n$, where $rect_n$ is $1$ on $\langle -n,n \rangle$ and $0$ otherwise. Why say "this is how an "approximate" fourier transform of a periodic function looks" when it really depends on how we approximate it?

Comment: @JohnP This answer is 1.5 years old. I don't even remember what I plotted. I can´t help before I get home from work. If you are interested you can read up on different kernels like Fejer and Dirichlet kernels. Maybe it will shed light on the issue meanwhile I finish work.

Comment: @mathreadler Hi, I just remembered this question. Would you please take a look and try to remember what is that you plotted? Already mentioned my question in my first comment (4 comments above this one).

Comment: @JohnP I plotted the Discrete Fourier Transform amplitude spectrum for the 24th power of a cosine. It was to show that a periodic function will have a train of "spikes" (Dirac $\delta$ distributions) like the one above, evenly distributed at $k\omega$ for integers $k$ where $\omega$ is the base frequency. What differs between the family of periodic functions of this particular frequency $\omega$ is the amplitudes and phases of each of these spikes.

Comment: @mathreadler The thing I don't understand is that when you're doing the fourier transform of a periodic function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, it's not even properly defined in some sense. The integral isn't defined. So I assume you first multiply it by some sort of envelope like the rectangle function (described above) and take the limit. Or how else do you do the fourier transform of a periodic function? But then the spectrum depends on the envelope you choose.

Comment: @mathreadler If for example we take the fourier transform of your function as $\xi \mapsto \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int (\cos^{24}(x) rect_n(x) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} )dx$, then the graph will not look like your plot - it will instead look like a sum of translated and scaled $sinc$ functions - there will still be "peaks", but it will also be very messy all around.

Comment: I mentioned in a comment that I did the DFT. Not the continous transform. Also it is boxes which correspond to sincs in Fourier domain, not dirac functions. Just look at the ideal band pass filters in the dicrete Shannon wavelets if you don't believe me.